# Remove part of border

Tags: html, css

I have a widget which **cannot** be wrapped in another div.

My question is how do I remove the border from the header/title-bar but still keep it around the remainder of the DIV? Example below.

*Adding a border to only .body isn't feasible because if an end-user adds padding to the bottom/top of the widget div things break.*

[image: Image issue]

```
<div class="widget">
    <div class="header">Header Title</div>
    <div class="body">My Content</div>
</div>


.widget {
    height: 100px;
    width: 130px;
    border: 3px solid blue;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.header {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 24px;
    max-height: 24px;
    display: block;
    background-color: grey;
    color: white;
}
.body {
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(100% - 24px);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/botwfngv/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/botwfngv/1/

Comment: Unfortunately, `overflow: hidden;` should be removed, otherwise you can not cover border of the parent by the child.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
.widget {
    height: 100px;
    width: 130px;
    border: 3px solid blue;
    position: absolute;
}
.header {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 24px;
    max-height: 24px;
    display: block;
    background-color: grey;
    color: white;
    margin: -3px;
    padding: 3px;
}
.body {
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(100% - 24px);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/botwfngv/2/

Comment: Just change the `margin` and `padding` to `-3px` and `3px` to fit the `border`. +1

Comment: @MelanciaUK yea, high resolution screen, can not see small details )) Thanx

Comment: Bonus point if you can figure out why bootstrap breaks this.. =\  http://jsfiddle.net/botwfngv/3/

Comment: @Mr.White remove `width: 100%;` for `.header`

Comment: Genius... Also setting box-sizing:initial fixes too.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the result by CSS2 only, just add borders to the `body`, not the whole `widget`:

```
.widget {
    width: 130px;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 25px;
}

.header {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 24px;
    max-height: 24px;
    display: block;
    background-color: grey;
    color: white;
    padding: 3px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    border: 3px solid blue;
    border-top-width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 30px;
}
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/botwfngv/5/).

Comment: @Mr.White Oooops, my mistake. I've updated my answer... (pay attention to `padding` I've added to `widget`.